# Cannot remove photos from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, photos

I have some photos I want to put into my iPhone. So I used iTunes when I chosen my folder with photos:

[image]

I synced it and they appear in my iPhone. But I can't remove any of them (from iPhone). How can I make them "deletable"? If this is a feature, it is a really stupid feature.

Comment: Not posted as an answer, as you specify iTunes, but if you use iCloud Photo Library any photos you add from your computer in the Photos app will be synced to iCloud and then to your phone. Photos then can be deleted from any devices (but will then be deleted from iCloud for all devices).

Comment: @DavidRouse thanks, I managed to work through iCloud.

Answer (score 2):

Photos synced from iTunes can't be deleted on the device because they'll be synced back to the device next time. To remove synced photos, uncheck Sync Photos.

Comment: And how else can I add photos to iPhone so they won't be synced? Some 3rd party application?

Comment: @debute You can use iCloud, AirDrop, or any third-party cloud storage app such as Dropbox or Google Drive.

Answer (score 1):

"If you add photos to your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch from iTunes, you can't delete them directly from your device in the Photos app. Learn [how to delete the photos from iTunes](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201313)."

https://support.apple.com/en-ph/HT205856